# CSS Text-align style in external stylesheet don`t work

Tags: html, css

Hi I`ve got basic html file + external css file. css file contain font-size class and text-align class but only font-size class actually work.  I try VS Studio code, Pycharm, and use .centered class on body, header, footer - still don`t work

Html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" >
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Title</title>

</head>
    <body class="centered">
                <header class="large" >
                    John Harvard
                </header>
                <main  class="medium">
                    Welcome to my page!
                </main>
                <footer class="small" >
                    Copyright &#169 John Harvard 1636
                </footer>


    </body>
</html>
```

CSS code:

```
<style>
       .centered {
               text-align: center;
           }
       .large {
           font-size: 70px;
           }
       .medium {
           font-size: medium;
           }
       .small {
           font-size: 3px;
           }

</style>
```

I try VS Studio code, Pycharm, and use .centered class on body, header, footer - still don`t work
Can you explain why?

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

Comment: How is named your `.css` file? `styles.css` or `style.css`?

Comment: Its working https://playcode.io/1000881

Comment: styles.css, and it`s in the same folder as .html file. It`s strange because it look like font-size  work great and only text-align won`t. Not all .css file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `CSS` file, you can NOT utilize `<style>` tags. To fix this, change your `CSS` file to the following:

```css
.centered {
   text-align: center;
}

.large {
   font-size: 70px;
}

.medium {
   font-size: medium;
}

.small {
   font-size: 3px;
}
```

All I did here was delete the first and last lines (`<style>` and `</style>`)

That should do it!

Comment: This is correct answer, I didn`t delete <style> tags after I copy css code from  <head> section of html file to separate .css file. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to align all the text in the body to center then you don't give body a class name, you just call upon it like this:

```
body {
     text-align: center;
}
```

(Reminder: do not to call upon body in your CSS style sheet like a class or an id, so .body or #body would be wrong, its just body.)

If you want to create a container or wrapper called "centered"
you would create a div as such:

```
<div class="centered"></div>
```

then you would use CSS:

```
.centered {
       text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Like I said on another answer, `<center>` is deprecated as of `HTML5`, and inline styling is discouraged. The OP (original poster) wanted a class `.centered` to be centered, not the whole body. For the `CSS` given, that's exactly what the OP did, but it wasn't working. This does not solve the problem. Take a look at my answer.

Comment: Yes I agree with your answer. That's why I included the two ways that are more efficient. I didn't see your answer when I was filling mine out. However, I included the latter options just to let the OP know that they are still options. I would use a style sheet and align accordingly in there whether it be calling on the body or making a container or wrapper.

Answer (score -1):

There are a lot of ways to center a text in HTML, the first one is to type

```
<center> Your text here </center>
```

in the HTML file, the other one is put all your text in a div, and add a css style in that div with this code inside

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Basically in your case, i would just replace

```
<body class="centered">
```

with

```
<body style="margin: 0 auto;" class="centered">
```

Comment: This is not the correct answer - see my answer below. Other than that, `<center>` is not supported in `HTML5`, it has been deprecated. Inline styling is highly discouraged as well, it removes all sanity from the code.